# How to query firestore with the Dialogflow inline editor to get information

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, dialogflow-es

I am using the inline editor within Dialogflow with the aim of making queries to the database I have created within Firestore.
In short, the user requests a list of courses, I'd like the chatbot to then grab that information form the db and display that back to the user.
Below I have tried to create a function that will do this, I want to take the user input, say "Art Courses" and have my db return those results.

So far, I have created a function that is triggered when the intent is matched, like so;

```
 function getCourses(agent){
    let courseRequest = agent.parameters.courseRequest;
    if (getCourses){
        console.log('Here is the list you requested for ${getCourses}' + parameters.courseRequest);
        return admin.firestore().collection('Course_Information').doc.where('CoureTypes').get();
    } 
}
```

Are there any notable things I need to add to my function to perform what I wish to achieve? 
Thank you.

**UPDATE**

This code deploys fine, but when I communicate with my bot and trigger the CourseEnquiry intent, cloud Functions shows this error:

```
admin.collection is not a function
```

Whilst this seems self explanatory I can't make sure of what it means, I thought declaring `const admin = require('firebase-admin');`enables me to use `admin.collection`

```
// See https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs
// for Dialogflow fulfillment library docs, samples, and to report issues
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  function getDate(agent){
      var today = new Date();
  }

  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
  }

  function test(agent){
      agent.add("The test is successful");
  }  

    function getCourses(agent){
        // Get the database collection and document
    const getCourseDoc = admin.collection('Course_Information').doc('Course_Types');

    return getCourseDoc.get()
      .then(doc => {
        if (!doc.exists) {
          agent.add('No data found in the database!');
        } else {
          agent.add(doc.data().entry);
        }
        return Promise.resolve('Here is the information you wanted');
      }).catch(() => {
        agent.add('Error reading entry from the Firestore database.');

      });
  }  

    function getSubmissionDateSep(agent){
            agent.add('Your next submission date is for coursework 1 is');    
    }

  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Test_Test', test);
  intentMap.set('CourseEnquiry', getCourses);
  intentMap.set('Submission_Dates - sept', getSubmissionDateSep);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

**UPDATE #2**

Hey guys, still not got anywhere with this, I have tried adding:

```
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.firestore();
```

According to [this](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-firestore-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js) document but I get this error when deploying:

```
The deployment of your Cloud Function failed:
Function load error: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Is there a syntax error in your code?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Firebase config variables are not available. Please use the latest version of the Firebase CLI to deploy this function.
```

Comment: Can you update the question clarify what you mean by "doesn't want to deploy". Where have you put this in your code? What errors, exactly, are you getting when you try to deploy?

Comment: Hey thanks for the response @Prisoner, I have updated the question with more explanation.

Comment: What is the entry for "firebase-admin" and "firebase-functions" in your package.json file? If you read the rest of the message, it suggests that something is up with how `admin.initializeApp()` or `functions.config()` is now used based on a version change.

Comment: @Prisoner, this is what I have :

    `"firebase-admin": "^4.2.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.5.7"`

Comment: After some Googling, not too sure how to even check which version I should have, I do have npm installed if that helps.

Comment: Hang on... I thought you said you were using the Dialogflow inline editor. You shouldn't need npm to use that.

Comment: I am using the inline editor :) ... I literally installed npm about 2 mins before I posted saying I had it, but never needed it prior, I did some searching about versions etc after your last comment and all it was pointing towards was the npm, so i downloaded it just incase I needed it :/ I was scratching my head to be honest...uninstall
Are those versions I have outdated or something? the inline editor example on github doesn't seem to be doing anything different to me.

Comment: this github link seems to be using `firebase-functions:^2.0.2`, does that suggest mine is heavily outdated: [link](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-webhook-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js)

Comment: You are using older versions, but it should be deploying with the latest version of the libraries anyway. Still, specifying the most recent versions of firebase-functions and firebase-admin would be a good start in eliminating problems.

Comment: @Tipping44 has your problem been solved? You should probably update the post with the solution that worked for you. Or probably add an answer yourself.

Comment: I am facing a similar problem, basically.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show how you're responding to the user with your results, but you'll want to make sure you handle that as part of the `then()` clause in a Promise. Since the `get()` in the firestore collection returns a Promise, and you are returning it from your function, you need to make sure that the calling function treats it as a Promise, has a `then()` clause, and sends back the result as part of something inside this clause.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm new to this (clearly!) and so struggling to find any guides for making and returning queries!
I will try and implement what you mean and update with new implementation. Thank you.

Comment: Hey @Prisoner, I have updated the question with where I am now after taking your advice on board, am I on the right track here at all? Thank you