# Where do I write db queries when using Cloud Functions, Firestore and Python SDK for Dialoflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, dialogflow-es

I created a chatbot in Dialogflow and now have integrated it into my Python environment (PyCharm), I have connected Python to Google cloud platform (which is where my Cloud Functions, Cloud Firestore and Dialogflow accessibility lies), everything is connected fine, I know this because when I type something, the chatbot responds with the default of an intent. I have also tried writing to the DB to create something, as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) (which worked)

But as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51621553/take-dialogflow-intent-and-query-firestore) question, I wanted to be able to query the database when an intent was triggered, so my code had to change slightly; which is now this:

```
import os, json
import sys
import dialogflow
from dialogflow_v2beta1 import *
import firebase_admin
import requests.packages.urllib3
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
from firebase_admin import firestore
from firebase_admin import credentials
import requests.packages.urllib3
from Tkinter import *
from dialogflow_v2beta1 import agents_client
import Tkinter as tk
result = None
window = Tk()

def Response():
    #no need to use global here
    result = myText.get()
    displayText.configure(state='normal')
    displayText.insert(END, "User:"+ result + '\n')
    displayText.configure(state='disabled')

#Creating the GUI
myText = tk.StringVar()
window.resizable(False, False)
window.title("Chatbot")
window.geometry('400x400')
User_Input = tk.Entry(window, textvariable=myText, width=50).place(x=20, y=350)
subButton = tk.Button(window, text="Send", command=Response).place(x =350, y=350)
displayText = Text(window, height=20, width=40)
displayText.pack()
scroll = Scrollbar(window, command=displayText).pack(side=RIGHT)
window.mainloop()

#Initialize the firebase admin SDK
cred = credentials.Certificate('./file.json')
default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db = firestore.client()

def getCourse():
    doc_ref = db.collection(u"Course_Information").document(u"CourseTypes")
    try:
        doc = doc_ref.get()
        return 'Document data: {}'.format(doc.to_dict())
    except google.cloud.exceptions.NotFound:
        return 'Not found'

def detect_intent_text(project_id, session_id, text, language_code):
    GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=".chat-8.json"
    session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient(GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS)

    session = session_client.session_path(project_id, session_id)

    text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(
        text=text, language_code=language_code)

    query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)

    response = session_client.detect_intent(
        session=session, query_input=query_input)

queryText = [myText.get()]

res = detect_intent_text('chat-8', 'session-test', queryText, 'en')
intentName = res['query_result']['intent']['display_name']

if intentName == 'CourseEnquiry':
    reponse = getCourse()
    print json.dumps({
        'fulfillmentText': reponse,
    })
elif intentName == 'Greetings':
    print "Yo"

detect_intent_texts("chat-8","abc", queryText,"en-us")
```

which has now started to show an error when I run (no longer getting the bot response_;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ashley/PycharmProjects/Chatbot/venv/Chatbot.py", line 59, in <module>
    res = detect_intent_text('chat-8', 'session-test', queryText, 'en')
  File "C:/Users/Ashley/PycharmProjects/Chatbot/venv/Chatbot.py", line 45, in detect_intent_text
    session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient(GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS)
  File "C:\Users\Ashley\PycharmProjects\Chatbot\venv\lib\site-packages\dialogflow_v2\gapic\sessions_client.py", line 109, in __init__
    self.sessions_stub = (session_pb2.SessionsStub(channel))
  File "C:\Users\Ashley\PycharmProjects\Chatbot\venv\lib\site-packages\dialogflow_v2\proto\session_pb2.py", line 1248, in __init__
    self.DetectIntent = channel.unary_unary(
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'unary_unary'
```

I am presuming this has something to do with my back-end not being set up right, 
my Dialogflow webhook option is linked to a url provided in cloud Functions, but where do i write the db query code? In code, like I have above in the getCourse() function, or in the cloud function themselves?

Comment: Have you taken a look at this Node.js sample?  It appears to be doing what your trying to accomplish: https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-firestore-nodejs

Comment: Thanks @matthewayne, are you able to assist here at all [link](http://https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51284263/how-to-query-firestore-with-the-dialogflow-inline-editor-to-get-information)
The link you supplied assists but having difficulties relating to that link and another question (See link) ... Thank you!

Comment: Have you figured out the answer to this question? if so please post an answer to your question so others with the same issue can benefit from what you've figured out

Comment: It's ongoing, I am still not certain, even with the link you provided I'm having trouble.... I am going back to my Dialogflow only environment temporarily and working within the inline editor, having trouble there too but as soon as I get past that I'll be focusing on this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Does the link I refer to help you answer your question?